# Is this language in NP?

Tags: math, graph, complexity-theory, path-finding, np

```
L={[G, K] | G is a simple undirected graph with no simple path longer than k}
```

(Further, is it Co-NP)?

I believe this is NP. I could provide a verifier that did the following:

> V(G,E, k) is a verifier, where G is the graph, E is an edge list for
>   the graph,  and k is the path provided.
>
> First, check to make sure the path is valid. Second, Begin searching
>   for a path longer than the given path.  If there is one, it can be
>   found in polynomial time. However, if there is NOT one, because this
>   is an undirected graph, this could  check for an infinite amount of
>   time, making this problem NP-Hard.

Where are the flaws in my thought process?

Comment: Do you mean "path without node repetition no loger than k"?

Comment: Yes, let's assume it's a simple path. Editing question now;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complement of your problem *L*, call it *L'*, is ``Given a graph *G=(V,E)* and an integer *k*, does *G* contain a simple path of length at least *k+1*'', which is the well-known `LONGEST-PATH` problem. The problem *L'* is clearly in **NP**: Just guess the path, assuming there is one. (Equivalently, given a path, just verify it is indeed of length at least *k+1*.) Note that the problem is in **coNP** if and only if its complement is in **NP**, meaning *L* is in **coNP**.

Because `LONGEST-PATH` is **NP**-complete, *L* is not in **NP** unless **coNP**=**NP**. (Because we believe **coNP** != **NP**, this implies no **NP**-complete problem can belong to **coNP** and no **coNP**-complete problem can belong to **NP**. See [Arora-Barak book](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/theory/complexity/) for details.)